# function not working in jsp page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

```
<script>
function KeepCount() {

    var x=0;
    var count=0;
    var x;
            for(x=0; x<document.QuestionGenerate.elements["questions"].length; x++){

            if(document.QuestionGenerate.elements["questions"][x].checked==true || document.QuestionGenerate.elements["option"][x].checked==true || document.QuestionGenerate.elements["Description"][x].checked==true || document.QuestionGenerate.elements["fillups"][x].checked==true){

                   count= count+1;
                   document.getElementsByName("t1")[0].value=count;    
                }
                else
                    {

                     document.getElementsByName("t1")[0].value=count;

                     //var vn=$('#t1').val();
                   // alert(vn);

                    //alert(vn);
                      //alert("value is"+count);
                    }
            }

           // var cc = document.getElementsByName("t1")[0].value;

            var vn=$('#t1').val();
            alert(vn);

            if(vn==0){
                alert("You must choose at least 1");
               return false;
            }
        }




</script>

<form action="SelectedQuestions.jsp" method="post" name="QuestionGenerate">



  <input type="text" name="t1" id="t1" value="">
<input type="submit" id="fi" name="s" value="Finish" onclick="return KeepCount();">
</form>
```

I use the above code for checking how many check box are checked  in my form my form having many check box. and if no check box are selected means it shows some message and than submit the form but for loop is working good and textbox get the value after the for loop the bellow code doesn't work even alert() is not working

**

```
var vn=$('#t1').val();
                alert(vn);

                if(vn==0){
                    alert("You must choose at least 1");
                   return false;
                }
```

This code is not working why?

**

Comment: You have defined same variable `vn` twice in function. First inside `else` part and second just before `alert()`

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar i changed but it is not working

Comment: any error in browser console? as you have used jQuery too, so makesure you have jquery available on the page.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar code after the for loop is not reaching

Comment: _the bellow code doesn't work even alert() is not working_ have you added `jquery` lib ? i dont know why this question has 3 upvotes

Comment: please share html code with checkbox for which you are running the loop, this way we can help you better.

Comment: @jai 
I am using jquery1.11.0.min.js

Comment: @sanDecruz  I am using jquery1.11.0.min.js

Comment: @KVK Can you update your code with exactly what you are trying to do ? or even it is better if you could create a jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change my KeepCount() function code shown in bellow that solve my problem

```
 function KeepCount()
  {


          var check=$("input:checkbox:checked").length;
          alert(check);

          if(check==0)
              {
              alert("You must choose at least 1");
              }
    return false;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The bug is : ***document.QuestionGenerate.elements["questions"] it is undefined***  that's why the code is not even going inside for loop use instead :

***document.QuestionGenerate.elements.length***

Comment: for loop is working good but the code bellow the for loop is not working i am using jquery1.11.0.min.js

Comment: Please share entire code to me. As I checked it through running on browser with the provided code and it didn't work. So share the code.